# How exactly is x86 memory model stronger than acquire-release?

Tags: x86, memory-barriers, memory-model

I've seen in a couple of places (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314179/c-how-is-release-and-acquire-achieved-on-x86-only-using-mov)) that x86 memory model has slightly stronger than pure acquire-release semantics.

What are the specific reordering constraints that x86 has that acquire-release doesn't?

Comment: A total store order (no IRIW reordering / disagreement) is a major one.  [Will two atomic writes to different locations in different threads always be seen in the same order by other threads?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50679223)  x86's memory model is program order + a store buffer with store-forwarding, with a total store order.  The existence of a total order of stores might be the only difference.  (Unless you want to get into the fact that ISO C++'s memory model doesn't depend on the existence of coherent cache at all, and makes guarantees based only on loads seeing stores -> happens-before)