# How CPUs Use the LOCK Prefix to Implement Cache Locking and ensure memory consistency

Tags: java, volatile, cpu-cache, memory-barriers, mesi

In Java, adding the volatile keyword to a variable guarantees memory consistency (or visibility).

On the x86 platform, the Hotspot virtual machine implements volatile variable memory consistency by adding a Lock prefix instruction.

Like this：lock addl $0x0,(%esp);

Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual：

> For the Intel486 and Pentium processors, the LOCK# signal is always
> asserted on the bus during a LOCK operation, even if the area of
> memory being locked is cached in the processor.
>
> For the P6 and more recent processor families, if the area of memory
> being locked during a LOCK operation is cached in the processor that
> is performing the LOCK operation as write-back memory and is
> completely contained in a cache line, the processor may not assert the
> LOCK# signal on the bus. Instead, it will modify the memory location
> internally and allow it’s cache coherency mechanism to ensure that the
> operation is carried out atomically. This operation is called “cache
> locking. “ The cache coherency mechanism automatically prevents two or
> more processors that have cached the same area of memory from
> simultaneously modifying data in that area.

I think "if the area of memory being locked during a LOCK operation is cached in the processor" means cache line state is S、E or M（may be E or M?)。

I have read a lot of information, and they say that cache locking is implemented through the MESI protocol.

I have read the MESI protocol, but I still have many doubts that I have not been able to solve.

First, can MESI implement cache locking? Second, how does the lock instruction achieve memory consistency?

```
// volatile write
if (cache->is_volatile()) {
    //
    if (tos_type == itos) {
        obj->release_int_field_put(field_offset, STACK_INT(-1));
    } else if (tos_type == atos) {
        VERIFY_OOP(STACK_OBJECT(-1));
        obj->release_obj_field_put(field_offset, STACK_OBJECT(-1));
    } else if (tos_type == btos) {
        obj->release_byte_field_put(field_offset, STACK_INT(-1));
    } else if (tos_type == ztos) {
        int bool_field = STACK_INT(-1);  // only store LSB
        obj->release_byte_field_put(field_offset, (bool_field & 1));
    } else if (tos_type == ltos) {
        obj->release_long_field_put(field_offset, STACK_LONG(-1));
    } else if (tos_type == ctos) {
        obj->release_char_field_put(field_offset, STACK_INT(-1));
    } else if (tos_type == stos) {
        obj->release_short_field_put(field_offset, STACK_INT(-1));
    } else if (tos_type == ftos) {
        obj->release_float_field_put(field_offset, STACK_FLOAT(-1));
    } else {
        obj->release_double_field_put(field_offset, STACK_DOUBLE(-1));
    }
    // after volatile write，insert storeload memory barrier
    OrderAccess::storeload();
} 
================================
inline void OrderAccess::storeload()  { 
    fence(); 
}
================================
inline void OrderAccess::fence() {
  if (os::is_MP()) {
    // always use locked addl since mfence is sometimes expensive
#ifdef AMD64
    __asm__ volatile ("lock; addl $0,0(%%rsp)" : : : "cc", "memory");
#else
    __asm__ volatile ("lock; addl $0,0(%%esp)" : : : "cc", "memory");
#endif
  }
}
```

(One thing that confuses me is that this Lock prefix is executed after the volatile write, and it's all already after the volatile write, so what can be locked?)

I Think MESI cannot guarantee memory consistency after introducing Store Buffer and Invalidate queue.

[image: image111]

I think "release_int_field_put" means write value into store buffer?

so,What does "**asm** volatile ("lock; addl $0,0(%%rsp)" : : : "cc", "memory");" do to ensure memory consistency?

Suppose there is a volatile variable that has been loaded into the cache by 3 CPUs，CPU1，CPU2，CPU3，now their Cache Line state are all S。

[image: image222]

According to the MESI protocol, CPU3 starts to write the volatile variable. Because the status of CPU3's Cache Line is S, so while writing the modification to the Store buffer, it also sends an Invalidate message to the address bus to invalidate the Cache Lines of other CPUs**（RFO）**. After receiving the Invalidate message, CPU1 and CPU2 send Invalidate ACK, and then change the status of their Cache Line to I. Under normal circumstances, after CPU3 receives ACKs from all other CPUs, it will change its Cache Line status to E, then flush the Store Buffer into the Cache Line, and finally change the Cache Line status to M. At this time, if CPU1 initiates a local read, because its Cache Line status is invalid, it initiates a read request to the bus, and the bus broadcasts the read request. After CPU3 receives the read request, it finds that its Cache Line status is M. According to the MESI protocol, It needs to be written back to the memory first, and then CPU1 reads from the memory. This ensures that CPU1 reads the latest data.

Will the following described situation happen?
**If CPU1 has already sent ACK, but CPU2 is busy and has not sent ACK, CPU3 will not flush the Store Buffer to the Cache Line until it receives ACKs from all other processors.** Therefore, the Store Buffer contains the new value at this time, but the Cache Line state of CPU3 is still S, and the old value is still inside. Similarly, the memory still holds the old value. However, at this time, CPU1 starts a local read, finds that its Cache Line state is I, and therefore initiates a read request to the bus. Since the Cache Line of CPU3 is still S at this time, the old value is finally obtained from the memory. This is why MESI cannot guarantee memory consistency after adding Store Buffer.

The above process is shown below：

CPU1  read A
[image: image333]
CPU2 read A
[image: image444]
CPU3 read A
[image: image555]
CPU 3 modifies the contents of A in the register and write it to the Store Buffer.
[image: image666]

There must be a mechanism that guarantees that when CPU3 writes to a Cache Line, other processors cannot read or write to this Cache Line, so that CPU can complete a complete write, write the value to the Cache, and then change the state of the Cache Line to M. So who provides this mechanism? MESI protocol? From my understanding, MESI doesn't seem to provide this mechanism. Lock prefix instruction? But from Intel's documentation, if it has been cached, it will not lock the bus, but the cache, and this cache lock, according to some people, is implemented by MESI. Therefore, I am confused.

I know that disabling reordering requires a memory barrier, but I'm wondering if for cache coherency, isn't the lock pair effectively a null operation when there's no need to send the lock# signal to the bus? Is the lock implemented through bus arbitration?

I'm even starting to suspect that the volatile guarantee of reading the latest value every time is wrong, and that the premise of being able to always get to the latest value every time is that every volatile write is written to memory (or in the Cache Line in the state of M) as an atomic operation, but this can't be done as I understand it now.
As I understand it, it only guarantees that each read must be from main memory.

Here's what I think a cache lock looks like, rather than relying solely on MESI:
When implementing a cache-based locking mechanism, the lock control unit usually consists of a cache controller and a lock status word

- When a CPU needs to access a shared resource, it sends a request to the cache and sets a lock flag on the lock status word.
- When a CPU needs to access a shared resource, it sends a request to the cache and sets a lock flag on the lock status word. The cache controller checks if another CPU has acquired the lock and prevents the other CPUs from accessing the shared resource until the current CPU releases the lock.

Comment: A terminology mistake in the title: `lock` is not an instruction or "prefix instruction", it is _instruction prefix_ (It doesn't make sense alone without  being followed by one of the instructions that support interlocked operation)

Comment: `lock add $0, (%rsp)` is a full memory barrier like any `lock`ed instruction: it waits for all earlier loads to complete and the store buffer to drain before doing the RMW, and no later loads can take a value from L1d cache until after it runs.  (Later stores could potentially be added to the store buffer; x86 commits stores in order, and any ISA only does so after they retire from the ROB = reorder buffer.)  Related: [Does lock xchg have the same behavior as mfence?](//stackoverflow.com/q/40409297) / [Which is a better write barrier on x86: lock+addl or xchgl?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4232660)

Comment: Also related: [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850) - my answer mentions how a CPU running `lock add` will keep the cache line pinned in Modified or Exclusive state from the load to the store, so it's Invalid in all other caches.  i.e. this core keeps exclusive ownership of the line the whole time.  (Not just Shared state, that would allow other reads to happen, or worse other atomic RMWs to start!)

Comment: In MESI, a core wanting to store needs to do a read-for-ownership to get a current copy of the line as well as invalidating other copies.  When it gets a reply to that, it has Exclusive ownership of that cache line, and committing the store flips the line from E to M state while no other caches have a valid copy.  x86's strong memory ordering rules already give acquire/release semantics (and no IRIW reordering), so recovering sequential consistency on top of that just requires blocking StoreLoad reordering between `volatile` accesses, e.g. use (implicit lock) `xchg` for pure stores.

Comment: See [C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314179) re: the other x86 memory-ordering rules that give that part.

Comment: I read the answer above, but I still don't understand how the lock prefix implements a lock (or exclusivity)

Comment: *MESI cannot guarantee memory consistency after introducing Store Buffer and Invalidate queue.* - `lock` waits for the store buffer to drain before doing the RMW.  So when the actual atomic RMW happens, it's like there's no store buffer.  But the real key is that not responding to MESI share requests or RFOs for that line between the load and store sides of an `xchg (%rdi), %eax` (implicit lock prefix on 386+ for xchg with mem).    That's how you'd normally take a lock, with an atomic RMW on the lock variable itself.

Comment: A dummy `lock add` to private stack memory is just `atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` which gives ordering but isn't sufficient to give mutual exclusion (like taking a spinlock), except with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm or similar.  Is that what you're asking, like you thought `asm volatile ("lock; addl $0,0(%%rsp)" : : : "cc", "memory");` was supposed to be taking a lock or giving mutual exclusion on its own?  It doesn't, it's just there to drain the store buffer after seq_cst stores if the JVM didn't use `xchg` for them in the first place, and to implement fences.

Comment: I see your edit added *if for cache coherency, isn't the lock pair effectively a null operation when there's no need to send the lock# signal to the bus?*  - so yes, you were missing the part where a `lock` prefix also locally drains the store buffer and prevents later loads from reading cache until that completes.  The MESI trickery of not replying to requests to share the cache line is what gives atomicity for the locked op itself, but what makes it a memory barrier is the other part, the part that `mfence` does, too (plus blocking OoO exec on some CPUs, making it slower.)

Comment: *so that CPU can complete a complete write, write the value to the Cache, and then change the state of the Cache Line to M* - The CPU has to *already* have exclusive ownership (E or M state) before it can commit a store from the store buffer to cache.  That plus MESI gives cache coherency, and with fences for ordering of accesses, gives as much consistency as you want.

Comment: Actually my question is what guarantees CPU can complete a complete write.
As I understand it, with the introduction of Store Buffer, MESI write operations are no longer atomic.
As I mentioned in my question, after writing to Store Buffer, it will not flush Store Buffer to Cache Line until all ACKs are received, and it will not change the state of Cache Line from S to E without writing to Cache.

To guarantee a complete CPU write, a lock is needed on the Cache Line. but i thind this lock is not provided by the MESI protocol.

Comment: *MESI write operations are no longer atomic.*  No, commit to L1d cache is still atomic.  Either the new 32 or 64 or 128 bits (or whatever) are visible or they're not, there are no torn writes.  That only requires coherency.  *Consistency* (ordering between operations, especially on different locations) is a different problem; that's what the dummy `lock`ed operation is doing, as an alternative to `mfence`.  The atomic-RMW operation that's made atomic by the `lock` prefix is totally and actually undesired, we're just doing it because it's still faster than `mfence`.

Comment: You don't need special asm instructions to make stores atomic, they're guaranteed atomic by the ISA (given size/alignment requirements) so the CPU hardware makes sure the process of committing from store buffer to cache is done safely/correctly all the time.  Even just to maintain coherency, regardless of ordering, the hardware can't leave a race window between committing a store to cache and marking the line as MESI Modified.  In fact I'd expect it has to get Exclusive ownership *before* the store can commit, or at least in the same cycle.  It will *never* modify a Shared line.

Comment: Related: [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685056) re: the atomicity guarantees in x86 asm.  The CPU doesn't know the difference between plain `int` accesses and `.store(release)` or `.load(acquire)`; those differ only in compile-time optimization and ordering restrictions.

Comment: *There must be a mechanism that guarantees that when CPU3 writes to a Cache Line, other processors cannot read or write to this Cache Line,* - It's called a Read For Ownership (RFO), and never writing to a cache line before actually getting exclusive ownership.  This is the mechanism for the transition from Shared or Invalid to Exclusive or Modified state; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol#Read_For_Ownership

Comment: If you're worried about invalidation queues, AFAICT the only effect is that loads can appear to have happened extra early because a core actually loaded from a line where invalidation was pending.  They might widen the window for some kinds of reordering but AFAIK it's possible to explain any allowed memory reordering without considering them.

Comment: I know RFO, "CPU3 starts to write the volatile variable. Because the status of CPU3's Cache Line is S, so while writing the modification to the Store buffer, it also sends an Invalidate message to the address bus to invalidate the Cache Lines of other CPUs".
As I understand it, only when all ACKs are received, the Cache Line exclusivity can be acquired, that is, the modification of the Cache Line's state to E.
However, my problem is that before CPU3 receives all ACKs, the new value is written to the Store Buffer, but the Cache Line's exclusivity is not acquired yet.

Comment: I only saw your reply since you edited the question.  Tag people with @ username to notify them of replies.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  In the scenario you talk about in the question, where a read happens before the RFO is completed, the store hasn't completed either; it hasn't "happened yet".  It definitely *will* happen, it's in the store buffer and the store instruction has retired from the ROB (so it's non-speculative, not able to be rolled back if an interrupt happens), but it hasn't happened yet as far as other CPUs are concerned.

Comment: Store forwarding lets a core see its own stores early like I mentioned, which is why a full barrier (draining the store buffer) is used after SC stores to stop them reordering with SC loads.  See also [Globally Invisible load instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50609934) .  Note that release and acquire stores don't need to drain the store buffer; it's allowed for a release store to reorder with a later acquire load. Anyway, the `lock add` is used for its side-effect of draining the store buffer for SC stores. `mfence` would work, too, the atomic RMW part of that `lock add` isn't useful.

Comment: I'm even considering if it's bus arbitration, when CPU3 receives all the Invalidate ACKs, the memory address is actually locked, and other processors are prevented from reading or writing to it until CPU3 receives all the ACKs.

Comment: I just want to find that lock that allows the CPU to complete a complete write and is atomic.
I don't see that lock in the Lock prefix.
The MESI protocol, with the addition of Store Buffer, doesn't implement this lock either in my opinion
I'm even wondering now if it's just a guarantee that every volatile read is read from main memory?
It doesn't guarantee that every read will be the latest value, because the latest value might still be in the Store Buffer. @Peter Cordes

Comment: Java is not relevant to this question.  How Java maps `volatile` to instructions is implementation dependent.  Indeed, the Java Memory Model is specified in a way that is independent of any concrete implementation mechanisms.  Instead, the JMM is specified in terms of *happens before* relations and the resulting memory visibility guarantees.

Comment: happens-before is just an abstraction, it's still dependent on the underlying implementation, either hardware or software, so isn't it the implementation we're talking about?

Comment: I'm wondering if RFO is an atomic operation?

Comment: I saw someone ask a question similar to mine。https://groups.google.com/g/mechanical-sympathy/c/Dh8zX-hWpVQ?pli=1
I think he thinks the RFO is an atomic operation, and he's asking how memory consistency is guaranteed in the time gap before the ACK is acknowledged and written to the Cache Line

Comment: @Triassic: RFO doesn't modify anything, it just transfers a cache line and gets MESI ownership of it.  IDK if it makes any sense to talk about it "being atomic".  Cache-line transfers don't have to be atomic on x86, only avoid tearing within 8-byte boundaries.  (Or 16-byte boundaries on CPUs with `lock cmpxchg16b`)  [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36685056)  .  Java `volatile` only works on things up to 8 bytes in size, right?  (Or on references which work like pointers and are <= 8 bytes.)

Comment: @Triassic: Java `volatile` is like C++ atomic with `memory_order_seq_cst`, IIRC, so `volatile` assignments can use a fence after a plain store (on x86) to make sure this core doesn't do any memory operations on this or other memory locations while waiting for the store buffer to drain and this store to be visible to other cores (via coherent cache, not main memory).  `mfence` is one such memory barrier, `lock addl $0, (%rsp)` is just an optimization.  Like I've told you already, the actual atomic-RMW part of that `lock add` is irrelevant, we just the fence part that matters.

Comment: Fence after a plain store is done precisely because of the weirdness that a store buffer would introduce in terms of ordering.  (But not because of any lack of atomicity or coherency, only because of the very strong consistency requirement: sequential.)

Comment: I understand what you are saying about fences.
What I'm asking about is memory consistency.
The description of volatile I saw: a write to a volatile variable is immediately visible to other processors (or threads).
So I'm trying to understand why a write to a volatile variable is visible to other processors. I looked at MESI, and also Lock prefix, but I have doubts, after the introduction of Store Buffer, a write to a volatile variable is not a direct write to the Cache Line. when the Store Buffer and the Cache Line don't coincide, is the variable still visible to other processors?

Comment: Ok yes, that description of volatile writes is confusing at best.  No other `volatile` memory operations (load or store) in this thread can happen until the volatile write is visible to all other threads.  But that's achieved by a fence in this thread that waits for visibility, not by somehow making inter-core latency zero.  So "immediately" means "before any more stuff happens in this thread" (in program-order steps) , not "zero nanoseconds or clock cycles" (absolute time).

Comment: Also, unless Java `volatile` is different from C++ `memory_order_seq_cst`, a volatile write *can* reorder with later non-volatile loads and non-release stores.  So it can use AArch64 `stlr` which has a special interaction with `ldar` that blocks StoreLoad reordering between those two instructions, but not with `ldr` used for relaxed or non-atomic loads.  And not with `ldapr` used for plain acquire not seq_cst.  That's why I said "no other volatile memory ops" rather than "no other memory ops at all".  (On most ISAs incl x86, only a full barrier is strong enough, so no mem ops at all.)

Comment: Also, you keep forgetting to notify me of your replies with @Peter.  Again I only happened to see your comment since your edit bumped the question.

Comment: *when the Store Buffer and the Cache Line don't coincide, is the variable still visible to other processors?* - No, it's not.  The store buffer is thread-private and not coherent.  The point of visibility for stores is commit from the store buffer to L1d cache.  (Or on PowerPC, SMT siblings sharing the physical core can store-forward from retired but not committed stores.  [This is the mechanism for IRIW reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807118/will-two-atomic-writes-to-different-locations-in-different-threads-always-be-see).)

Comment: While the store is sitting in the store buffer, it hasn't "happened" yet.  A full barrier (like `mfence` or a dummy `lock`ed operation) will wait for it to happen before later memory operations can happen.  This is sufficient to recover sequential consistency in a data-race-free program (all shared data is `volatile` or protected by mutexes).